Hotspot vs home internet
I need to know if when I’m using my hotspot, does it also use up my home WiFi? I’ve asked multiple people that question and as of yet, not received any clear answers. I go to my smart tv and go to settings then choose my iPhone as my option for wireless. I want to know if my Hugh’s net is working in conjunction with my hotspot. I’m going through all the hughesnet WiFi within the first week of a new cycle even though I’m connected to my hotspot.

Could you add what are the names you see of these 2 Wi-Fi networks?

Forgive me to be so heavy. When you talk of "my hotspot", which one is it? Which is its name. Otherwise we cannot be sure if you speak of an iPhone hotspot, an Android hotspot, the hotspot from your Huguesnet router.

If you use the untethered hotspot functionality (connect via WiFi) of your iPhone, and the iPhone uses the 4G/5G data network provived by your mobile carrier, your home WiFi is not used.
PS: You can easily verify this by turning the home WiFi off and check whether your TV still can access the Internet.

Do iPhones automatically switch to 4G/5G when the hotspot function is enabled? Some other phones will serve the hotspot Wi-Fi from any connection they have available – including from an existing home Wi-Fi connection (as sort of range extender).

iPhones cannot use WiFi as a WiFi hotspot.

I will bet you meant your hotspot is started from your iPhone
with the function
Settings > Personal Hotspot > Allow Others to Join.
( If this is wrong, please clarify your original question ).

Your hotspot network has a name you see when you select it to connect to.
Let's say this name is "Terri hotspot".

Your home Wi-Fi, has another name, one you defined on your router or was
automatically defined by your provider. In this last case, this name is
usually printed on a sticker on the router box.
Anyway you also see its name when you select it to connect to.
Let's say it is "Huguesnet home network".


From the name you choose to connect to, "Terry hotspot" or
"Huguesnet home network", you fully know on which network
you are connected. And then you know if you are using your mobile phone
network or your Huguesnet network.

The question is are you sure? Because recent android versions thether through the wifi they are connected to (if they are connected to a wifi). And only thether through the mobile network when they are not connected to a wifi. Idk how the iphone works but it's not inconceivable that it might be still piping the connection through the wifi in case it is connected to it at the time.

Sure of what?
Anyway, we are not dealing with Android here but with iOS.

Just asking. Maybe it doesn't support sharing of another wifi network. Just saying that things that were true a few year ago, may not be true now. Or may not be true in an year or two.
